# Problem adding controls during runtime (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm having issues adding controls during runtime in winforms c#. It works, but it takes super long time.

I'm trying to add 'Control's containing labels to a TableLayoutPanel (named productTable).

Here is the code:

```
private void loadTable()
        {
            List<Product> prodList = controller.getAllProducts();
            List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
            List<Game> gameList = new List<Game>();
            List<DVD> dvdList = new List<DVD>();
            foreach(Product p in prodList)
            {
                if (p is Book)
                {
                    bookList.Add((Book)p);
                }
                else if (p is Game)
                {
                    gameList.Add((Game)p);
                }
                else if (p is DVD)
                {
                    dvdList.Add((DVD)p);
                }
            }
            if (bookList.Any())
            {
                int control = 0;
                productTable.RowCount = productTable.RowCount + 1;
                foreach (string val in bookList.First().getTitlesList())
                {
                    productTable.Controls.Add(new Label()
                    {
                        Text = val,
                        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver,
                        Font = new Font(Label.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)
                    }, control, productTable.RowCount);
                    control += 1;
                }
                foreach(Book book in bookList)
                {
                    control = 0;
                    productTable.RowCount = productTable.RowCount + 1;
                    foreach (string val in book.getValuesAsStringList())
                    {
                        productTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = val }, control, productTable.RowCount);
                        control += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (gameList.Any())
            {
                int control = 0;
                productTable.RowCount = productTable.RowCount + 1;
                foreach (string val in gameList.First().getTitlesList())
                {
                    productTable.Controls.Add(new Label()
                    {
                        Text = val,
                        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver,
                        Font = new Font(Label.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)
                    }, control, productTable.RowCount);
                    control += 1;
                }
                foreach (Game game in gameList)
                {
                    control = 0;
                    productTable.RowCount = productTable.RowCount + 1;
                    foreach (string val in game.getValuesAsStringList())
                    {
                        productTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = val }, control, productTable.RowCount);
                        control += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (gameList.Any())
            {
                int control = 0;
                productTable.RowCount = productTable.RowCount + 1;
                foreach (string val in dvdList.First().getTitlesList())
                {
                    productTable.Controls.Add(new Label()
                    {
                        Text = val,
                        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver,
                        Font = new Font(Label.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)
                    }, control, productTable.RowCount);
                    control += 1;
                }
                foreach (DVD dvd in dvdList)
                {
                    control = 0;
                    productTable.RowCount = productTable.RowCount + 1;
                    foreach (string val in dvd.getValuesAsStringList())
                    {
                        productTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = val }, control, productTable.RowCount);
                        control += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

the 'controller' object in this case just fetches some data-objects (Products). And from the products in this case i only use to return lists of strings (with the metods getTitlesList() and getValuesAsStringList() ).

I run this method (loadTable()) at startup, in the FormMain constructor, and then it works fine and has no delay. But when i try to run the method during runtime with a button_click event, it takes forever (2-3 min). Even if the data has not changed. When I used the debugger it became obvious that its creating the Controls thats taking so much time. Even if i just put empty labels inside it. Actually just running the productTable.Controls.Clear(); takes a strange amount of time (2-3 sec).

Here you can see the problem in action: https://media2.giphy.com/media/ihMH62AYoCKSYuGQlC/giphy.gif

Comment: How many controls do you add? Always try to SuspendLayout while adding data or controls! When done use ResumeLayout on the container. - Also: Does the TLP have some sort of size calculations to do while you add controls? Try to turn that off until all is added or elese much time will be wasted on it..

Comment: Well that was easy.. I'm surprised i didn't find that method when researching the issues haha. Now it works like a charm, thanks pal!